# Rearranging divs with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've just started working with bootstrap and trying to make a responsive site for mobile and web.
This is the design I am trying to create.

[image: Wanted design]

I want 3, 4 and 5 to change order and this seems problematic. I've been with code similar to this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-push-sm-12 col-xs-12">
       3
    </div>
    <div class="col-pull-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        4
    </div>
</div>
```

But the columns just gets out of bounds and does not switch rows.

Is this possible to accomplish using just some bootstrap hax or is the correct way to do this by creating multiple divs which i hide and show depending on screen size?

Answer (score 1):

You can try it doing this way.

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lvqeG)

HTML

```
<div class="container outer">
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-6 staticPos">
       <div class="cont1">1</div>
      <div class="cont2">2</div>
      <div class="cont3">3</div>
      <div class="cont4">4</div>
      <div class="cont5">5</div>
    </div>
</div>  
</div>
```

CSS

```
.cont1 {background: green}
.cont2 {background: purple}
.cont3 {background: red}
.cont4 {background: blue}
.cont5 {background: yellow}
.staticPos {position: static}
.outer {position: relative}
.cont2 {position: absolute; right: 15px; top: 0;  width: calc(50% - 30px)}
.cont3 {position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 15px; width: calc(50% - 30px)}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .cont2, .cont3 {position: static; width: auto;}
}
```

Comment: This was a nice example. However I will go for creating multiple divs instead as it is easier to work with. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to reorder elements using just CSS and in any solution you'd have to do it without Bootstrap since it's grid system isn't compatible with these solutions.

- [Use `display: table-*-group` to reorder](http://tanalin.com/en/articles/css-block-order/) (only works with up to three elements, and support in old browsers is flacky)
- Use the new CSS [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) positioning system, which is only [supported by the newest browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex).